# Can a noun have two appositives separated by a comma?

Tags: commas

I know you can use commas, instead of and, to separate two or more coordinate adjectives. Similarly can a noun have multiple appositives separated by a comma instead of and? If the answer is yes, can you give an example in your answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Write.com](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/grammar/appositives/) gives this example:

> Multiple appositives:
>
> *The Great Depression, a time of great strife for many Americans, one of the nation’s toughest non-military challenges, affected many of
>   those who lived through it for the rest of their lives.*

Using an 'and' here would strongly suggest that what follows is completely new  information rather than largely a paraphrase.

Comment: So is it a bad practice to use multiple appositives with a comma as opposed to and?

Comment: The example given is fine, and I wouldn't want the 'and' in this example. I'd say the practice is uncommon. With << John, a gentleman and a scholar, naturally ... >> it wouldn't be sensible to drop it.